# What is the meaning of this statistics output?

Tags: haskell, ghc

So I have a `io-streams` based pipeline that I just ran (interpreted) and dumped the statistics with `-s`:

```
    123,680 bytes allocated in the heap
       3,464 bytes copied during GC
      68,912 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
      13,008 bytes maximum slop
           1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                 Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0002s

INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.001s  (299.935s elapsed)
GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
Total   time    0.134s  (299.936s elapsed)

%GC     time       0.2%  (0.0% elapsed) 

Alloc rate    106,371,724 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  99.7% of total user, 0.0% of total elapsed
```

So basically no time was spend garbage collecting. But what I am confused about is the times in parenthesis. From [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-options-to-produce-runtime-statistics) it is not obvious what the difference between the times and the times in parenthesis is. Anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: it's CPU-time vs. wall-clock-time (what you would call time) - the first is the time spend *warming* the CPU - the other is you waiting for the result

Comment: in this case it seems you did lots of slow IO(?) / waiting for stuff to happen

Comment: btw: it's there in the docs: "Next there is the CPU time and wall clock time"

Comment: About 500mb reading and 500mb writing csv files. Wouldn't have thought that that is actually io bound.

Comment: 5minutes seems way to much to just read/write 500MB - but this is probably another question

Comment: Docs could probably be improved by stating "and wall clock time (in parenthesis)", there is probably a place to raise that issue. There is some processing involved, but if that stats are correct most of the time is spend waiting for the os to provide the data from disc?

Answer (score 1):

The time in parenthesis is the wall clock time. It's the time a human (you) experiences while the program is running if you look at a clock at the wall. The CPU time is the time your program experiences:

> If you use the `-s` flag then, when your program finishes, you will see something like this (the exact details will vary depending on what sort of RTS you have, e.g. you will only see profiling data if your RTS is compiled for profiling):
>
> ```
>     36,169,392 bytes allocated in the heap
>      4,057,632 bytes copied during GC
>      1,065,272 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
>         54,312 bytes maximum slop
>              3 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
>
> Generation 0:    67 collections,     0 parallel,  0.04s,  0.03s elapsed
> Generation 1:     2 collections,     0 parallel,  0.03s,  0.04s elapsed
>
> SPARKS: 359207 (557 converted, 149591 pruned)
>
> INIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
> MUT   time    0.01s  (  0.02s elapsed)
> GC    time    0.07s  (  0.07s elapsed)
> EXIT  time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
> Total time    0.08s  (  0.09s elapsed)
>
> %GC time      89.5%  (75.3% elapsed)
>
> Alloc rate    4,520,608,923 bytes per MUT second
>
> Productivity  10.5% of total user, 9.1% of total elapsed
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Next there is the CPU time and wall clock time elapsed broken down by what the runtime system was doing at the time. INIT is …

The wall clock time is usually greater than the CPU time, unless you use multiple cores at once. A simple example where the CPU time is *very* low and the wall clock time is high can be achieved by using `getLine`, `sleep` and `echo`:

```bash
$ {sleep 10; echo 1} | ghc -e 'getLine' +RTS -s > /dev/null

      32,006,664 bytes allocated in the heap
      20,644,024 bytes copied during GC
       5,813,624 bytes maximum residency (6 sample(s))
         156,360 bytes maximum slop
              12 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        37 colls,     0 par    0.011s   0.011s     0.0003s    0.0009s
  Gen  1         6 colls,     0 par    0.052s   0.052s     0.0087s    0.0105s

  TASKS: 5 (1 bound, 4 peak workers (4 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.016s  (  9.903s elapsed) <------------
  GC      time    0.063s  (  0.063s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.010s  (  0.010s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.125s  (  9.977s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,956,305,120 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  48.7% of total user, 0.6% of total elapsed
```

As you can see, the  MUT CPU time is small, whereas the MUT wall clock time is high, since the application waits for input.